# What will be the values of $firstVar and $secondVar after the code below is executed? Explain the answer please

Tags: php, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
<?php
$firstVar = '4';
$secondVar = &$firstVar;
$secondVar = "2$secondVar";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have the code above for which I wonder what the answer is in PHP. I get a answer is 24, is it correct?

Comment: See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php

Comment: What do you mean by this `"2$secondVar"` the & is used as reference type so it is 2 separate value and the value of $secoundVar is 4  which is actually 2 4, not 24

Comment: You are not gett8ng 2 4 but a string, "24".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
<?php
$firstVar = '4';
$secondVar = &$firstVar;
$secondVar = "2$secondVar";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

## $firstVar = '4';

creates a variable called `$firstVar`, initialized by the value of '4'.

## $secondVar = &$firstVar;

As we have seen, `$firstVar` is a variable, whose value is '4'. `$secondVar` is a new variable, initialized to point to the address of `$firstVar`, so whatever the value of `$firstVar` is will be the value of `$secondVar` as well.

## $secondVar = "2$secondVar";

This line evaluates the right-hand side first and assign the result to the variable at the left-hand side. This means that in the expression of "2$secondVar" the value of `$secondVar` is its "old" value, that is, the assignment did not happen yet. As a result, it will be evaluated as "24" and then this result will be assigned to `$secondVar`.

## An interesting experiment

Let's change `$firstVar` after `$secondVar` has been initialized, but before the final templating:

```
$firstVar = '4';
$secondVar = &$firstVar;
$firstVar = '5';
$secondVar = "2$secondVar";
echo var_dump($secondVar);
```

You will see that the result is 25. This way, hopefully the benefits of using addresses becomes clear.

Answer (score 3):

The answer `24` is correct, and the method you are using here is called `Assigning by reference`.

Here you get more information about [Assigning by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php#language.operators.assignment.reference).